# mobile homescreen lost

Tags: home-screen, launcher

I have downloaded 2 icon packs for android. Now my phone don't work anymore.
I am working with smart launcher.
I can not even get in to settings or apps. My homescreen is black, but I can see on top the task bar, with notification for emails and our and I have netconnection.
what can I do??

Comment: What exactly are these "icon packs" you've downloaded?

Comment: Also, what Android version are you using? Please [edit] your question to add these details, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to `setting` by any way...

Like: in some launch screens you can get the settings screen via: `options->Device settings` or `Drag the task bar ->Settings`.

And then change the `Home screen settings` to previous home screen.

If these options not available, I think `Factory Reset` is the only option for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is connected to the net, try to install any other launcher from the play store website, for example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher

Wait the installation to finish on your phone, then press the home button. Now you will able to uninstall then reinstall SL or any other launchers.